# Why the variations on Ant plugin taskdefs?

Tags: java, plugins, ant, findbugs, cobertura

I'm really confused with the *proper* (most modern, best practices, etc.) way of defining taskdefs for Ant plugins. Below is a snippet of code that I pieced together taken from one of our in-house Java app's `build.xml`. Please note that all of the following Ant targets work perfect 100% (even though I've cut-n-pasted them together, and stripped out most of their contents for brevity's sake):

```
<project name="MyApp" default="package" basedir="." xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">
    <path id="cobertura.path">
        <!-- ... -->
    </path>

    <taskdef name="jacoco-coverage" classname="org.jacoco.ant.CoverageTask"/>
    <taskdef name="jacoco-report" classname="org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask"/>
    <taskdef classpathref="cobertura.path" resource="tasks.properties" />
    <taskdef name="findbugs" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask"/>

    <target name="run-coco" depends="doOtherStuff">
        <jacoco:coverage>
            <!-- ... -->
        </jacoco:covergae>

        <jacoco-report>
            <!-- ... -->
        </jacoco-report>        
    </target>

    <target name="findbugs">
        <antcall target="compile" />
        <findbugs home="${findbugs.home}" output="xml:withMessages" outputFile="findbugs.xml">
            <!-- ... -->
        </findbugs>
    </target>
</project>
```

1. Why do I need to define an XML namespace for JaCoCo but not for Findbugs?
2. What is antlib? Sometimes I see it inside the XML namespace definition, and sometimes it's not there.
3. Although both `jacoco-coverage` and `javacoco-report` taskdefs use a hyphen ("-") in their name, the corresponding tasks are called `jacoco:coverage` and `jacoco-report` respectively...why the colon (":") for coverage, and how does that even work (it does, trust me!)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's take this question one step at a time:

#### Step #1: Defining your task

You can define a task in one of two ways:

1. You can point to a class file, and then give the task that classfile defines a *name*.
2. You can point to *resource* file inside the jar that has the task names and the classfile that those task names use.

In your case for JaCoCo, you did the first:

```
<taskdef name="jacoco-coverage" 
    classname="org.jacoco.ant.CoverageTask"/>
<taskdef name="jacoco-report"
    classname="org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask"/>
```

However, you could do it the second way too:

```
<taskdef resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml"/>
```

If you open up the jacoco jar file and drill down in that directory, you will see a file called `antlib.xml`. If you look at that file, you will see this:

```
<antlib>
    <taskdef name="coverage"  classname="org.jacoco.ant.CoverageTask"/>
    <taskdef name="agent"     classname="org.jacoco.ant.AgentTask"/>
    <taskdef name="report"    classname="org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask"/>
    <taskdef name="merge"     classname="org.jacoco.ant.MergeTask"/>
    <taskdef name="dump"      classname="org.jacoco.ant.DumpTask"/>
</antlib>
```

So, if there is a resource file located in the jar, you can define all of your tasks with a single `<taskdef>`. Note that what you called `jacoco-coverage` is simply called `coverage` here and what you called `jacoco-report` is called `report` here.

Where you used `<jacoco-coverage/>` as an Ant task, I would use `<coverage/>`.

#### Step #2: Where's the JAR file?

In the above, I defined the task as:

```
<taskdef resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
```

Somewhere, Ant has to find that path in its classpath, but where? If you put the JaCoCo jar into your `$ANT_HOME/lib` folder, it will automatically included in your classpath. It makes defining the task very easy to do. Unfortunately, it also means that if someone else wants to run your Ant script, they'll have to download that JaCoCo jar and put it in their `$ANT_HOME/lib` folder. Not very portable.

Fortunately, you can specify where that JaCoCo jar is located. Since your project is usually under version control, the best place to put it is under your project's directory just below where the `build.xml` is located. When someone checks out your project, and the `build.xml`, they'll get the JaCoCo.jar too.

My preference is to create a directory called `antlib` and then create a subdirectory in that `antlib` directory for each and every set of tasks. In this case, I would have a directory called `antlib/jacoco`.

Once my jacoco.jar file is safely ensconced. in that directory, I can add a `<classpath>` sub-entity to my `<taskdef>` saying where to find `jacoco.jar`:

Before Classpath:

```
<taskdef resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml"/>
```

After Classpath:

```
<taskdef resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
   <classpath>
       <fileset dir="${basedir}/antlib/jacoco"/>
   </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Note by using `<fileset/>`, I don't care whether my JaCoCo jar file is called `jacoco.jar` or `jacoco-2.3.jar`. If you know the jar's exact name, you could do this:

```
<taskdef resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
   <classpath path="${basedir}/antlib/jacoco/jacoco.jar"/>
</taskdef>
```

And save a couple of lines.

#### Step #3: XML Namespace

As of this point, I don't need `jacoco:` prefixed to my task names.

I could simply do this:

```
<project name="MyApp" default="package" basedir=".">

    <taskdef resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
        <classpath path="${basedir}/antlib/jacoco/jacoco.jar"/>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="run-coco" depends="doOtherStuff">
        <coverage>
            <!-- ... -->
        <coverage>

        <report>
            <!-- ... -->
        <report>        
    </target>
</project>
```

And, you could leave it at that. No problems at all. Simple and clean.

However, what if you are using two different Ant task sets, one called `Foo` and one called `Bar`, and both happen to have a `<munge/>` task defined in them?

```
<taskdef resource="org/foo/ant/antlib.xml">
    <classpath path="${basedir}/antlib/foo.jar/>
</taskdef>

<taskdef resource="org/bar/ant/antlib.xml">
    <classpath path="${basedir}/antlib/bar.jar/>
</taskdef>

<target name="munge-this">
    <!-- Is this foo.jar's or bar.jar's munge task? -->
    <munge vorbix="fester"/>
</target>
```

Which `munge` task is being executed? Is it the one in `foo.jar` or the one in `bar.jar`?

To get around this, Ant allows you to define an *XML Namespace* for each set of tasks. You can define such a namespace in the very top `<project>` entity, inside a task itself, or in a `<target>` name. 99% of the time, it's done in the `<project>` entity.

```
<project name="demo" default="package" basename="."
    xmlns:foo="I-will-have-fries-with-that"
    xmlns:bar="Never-on-a-first-date">

 <taskdef uri="I-will-have-fries-with-that"
    resource="org/foo/ant/antlib.xml">
    <classpath path="${basedir}/antlib/foo.jar/>
</taskdef>

<taskdef uri="Never-on-a-first-date"
    resource="org/bar/ant/antlib.xml">
    <classpath path="${basedir}/antlib/bar.jar/>
</taskdef>

<target name="munge-this">
    <!-- Look the 'foo:' XMLNS prefix! It's foo.jar's much task! -->
    <foo:munge vorbix="fester"/>
</target>
```

Now, I know that this is the `<munge/>` task from the Foo task list!

The `xmlns` defines an XML namespace. The `xmlns:foo` defines a namespace for the Foo set of taks and the `xmlns:bar` defines it for the bar set of task. When I use a task from `foo.jar`, I prefix it with the `foo:` namespace. Note that this prefix is the one right after `xmlns:`.

The `uri` is merely a string that matches the namespace string. I used the strings `I-will-have-fries-with-that` and `Never-on-a-first-date` to show you that the strings themselves aren't important. What is important is that this string matches the `uri` parameter of the `<taskdef>` task. This way, tasks being defined know what *namespace* they should use.

Now, normally the URI string is a URI definition. There are two ways to go with this:

- Use an `antlib:` URI that is somewhat standardized, and uses that reverse naming for the namespace: `antlib:org.jacoco.ant`.
- Use the URL that points to the project: `http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/`.

I prefer the latter because it'll point to the documentation. However it looks like the first is more popular.

So, let's look at how Jacoco will work:

```
<project name="MyApp" default="package" basedir="."
    xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">

    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" 
        resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
        <classpath path="${basedir}/antlib/jacoco/jacoco.jar"/>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="run-coco" depends="doOtherStuff">
        <jacoco:coverage>
            <!-- ... -->
        <jacoco:coverage>

        <jacoco:report>
            <!-- ... -->
        <jacoco:report>        
    </target>
</project>
```

Note that the `uri` in the JaCoCo `<taskdef/>` is the same as the `xmlns:jacoco` string.

That's all there is to task definitions. I hope it explains where the `jacoco:` prefix comes and how you can define tasks by pointing to an actual classname that contains that class, or to a *resource* file that points to both the task name ***and*** the class.

Comment: Thanks @David W. (+1) - I wish I could upvote this more! Just so I understand, it looks like I have a hidden, inadvertent "bug" in my Ant script. It looks like since I'm calling `<jacoco:coverage>` in my `run-coco` target, that I'm actually calling the `<coverage>` task as defined by the antlib declaration. But then I have a taskdef explicitly defined called `jacoco-report`. Is this why both `jacoco:coverage` and `jacoco-report` work, even though one uses a colon and the other uses a hyphen? If so, it sounds like I should stick with the antlib and drop the XMLNS stuff altogether. Thanks again!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja I assumed that wasn't your entire `build.xml` file, and you did that for brevity. Somewhere (maybe in an imported file), you're including another taskdef that uses the `uri` parameter and using the `antlib.xml` file in the `jacoco.jar` to define the task. If that's the case, yes, that's why you can use both `jacoco-report` and `jacoco:coverage`. If that is the case, you could also use `jacoco-coverage` and `jacoco:report` too. In the old days before XML namespace issues, you'd define a task with your own taskname like `foo-munge` and `bar-munge` to get around name clashes.

Comment: @IAmYourFaja I hope my explanation cleared up how `<taskdef>` works, and how XML name space works. The `antlib` for XML namespace doesn't really mean a thing. As I showed, the XML namespace could be set any string at all. It just has to match and be unique. `antlib:path.to.antlib.xml` seems to be the standard to insure uniqueness. BTW, if I answered your question, please accept my answer.